# Firebase listener not working

Tags: android, firebase

I'm testing the new Firebase library for Android, and unfortunately it's not working, here is the code that i put on the onCreate MainActivity.method :

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://mydatabase.firebaseio.com/");

    // Read data and react to changes
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snap) {
            Log.e("FIREBASE", snap.getName() + " -> " + snap.getValue());
        }

        @Override public void onCancelled() { }
    });
```

Output : no message displayed and debug error :

```
07-15 00:01:49.020: D/ActionBarSherlock(13362): [callbackPrepareOptionsMenu] returning true
07-15 00:01:49.020: D/ActionBarSherlock(13362): [dispatchPrepareOptionsMenu] returning true
07-15 00:01:49.370: D/dalvikvm(13362): GC_CONCURRENT freed 263K, 4% free 9700K/10055K, paused 20ms+4ms
07-15 00:01:49.830: D/WebSocket(13362): ws_0 - closed with code -1 and reason: 
07-15 00:01:49.830: D/WebSocket(13362): ws_0 - closing itself
07-15 00:01:49.830: D/Connection(13362): conn_0 - Realtime connection failed
07-15 00:01:49.830: D/Connection(13362): conn_0 - closing realtime connection
07-15 00:01:49.830: D/PersistentConnection(13362): pc_0 - Got on disconnect
07-15 00:01:49.830: D/PersistentConnection(13362): pc_0 - Reconnecting in 0ms
07-15 00:01:49.830: D/ViewManager(13362): Raising events for /.info/connected
07-15 00:01:49.830: D/ViewManager(13362): Marking queries complete for /.info/connected
07-15 00:01:49.830: D/ViewManager(13362): Marking queryMap complete:null
07-15 00:01:49.840: D/Connection(13362): conn_1 - Opening a connection
07-15 00:01:50.670: D/WebSocket(13362): ws_1 - closed with code -1 and reason: 
07-15 00:01:50.670: D/WebSocket(13362): ws_1 - closing itself
07-15 00:01:50.670: D/Connection(13362): conn_1 - Realtime connection failed
07-15 00:01:50.670: D/Connection(13362): conn_1 - closing realtime connection
07-15 00:01:50.670: D/PersistentConnection(13362): pc_0 - Got on disconnect
07-15 00:01:50.670: D/PersistentConnection(13362): pc_0 - Reconnecting in 342ms
07-15 00:01:50.670: D/ViewManager(13362): Raising events for /.info/connected
07-15 00:01:50.670: D/ViewManager(13362): Marking queries complete for /.info/connected
07-15 00:01:50.670: D/ViewManager(13362): Marking queryMap complete:null
```

PS : I put the INTERNET permission on the AndroidManifest file.

PS 2 : I downloaded the chat example and it's not working too.

Comment: What version of Android are you running? Also, can you add the following to the top of your main activity and post the log output?

static { Firebase.getDefaultConfig().setLogLevel(Logger.Level.DEBUG); }

Comment: I tested the setLogLevel but it's showing nothing ... My android version : 4.0.4

Comment: if you include that code at the top of your main activity, it should add log messages to the logcat output ("adb -e logcat"). Are you not getting any messages there?

Comment: You mean there is no log output? Are you running on real hardware? In that case you'll need "adb -d logcat" to get the log output.

Comment: I put the error log returned

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I'll see if I can reproduce it and figure out what's going on. I suspect it's an SSL issue.

Comment: Yes that's my conclusion too. I'm ready to give any help :)

Comment: It appears to be this issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12955#c12

It'll take me a little while, but I'll work on getting a workaround in place.

Comment: Is there any news about this issue ?

Comment: Yup, I updated my answer below. Can you try the latest version of the SDK and see if you still have the issue?

Comment: Greg! you got all my respect :) It's working fine on Android 2.3.3 & 4.0.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an issue with Android 2.3's SSL implementation. We're working on an update to the library that works around it. Can you try running your app on an emulator with a version >= 3.0?

We just released a new version of the library (v1.0.2). Can you give it a try and see if it fixes the problem? It includes workarounds for some of the Android SSL limitations.

https://www.firebase.com/docs/downloads.html

Comment: Is there a public repo of the java library? I can check by myself to find a solution.

Comment: The client library is not open source at this time, although we may open source it in the future.